# What is this code block doing ? (u > 0) - (u < 0)

Tags: c, ansi-c

```
if (abs(u) > Vdc)
    u = Vdc*((u > 0) - (u < 0));
```

This code is in C 
considering we enter the if condition what will happen ?
Vdc = 24;
consider any arbitrary value of u for an explanation

Comment: It's an implicit type conversion from bool to an integer. You see, u will always be positive and may be greater than Vdc. U ends up being equal to Vdc * (1 (true) - 0)). Effectively, it's a longhand version of u = Vdc.

Comment: @Poriferous that is not true.  u can be negative (assuming it is declared as a signed int).

Comment: Certainly `u` better be an `int` or narrower signed integer, else `abs(u)`, which returns an `int`, is a problem.  `u == INT_MIN` is a problem. Code using `if (u > Vdc) u == Vdc else if (u < -Vdc) u = -Vdc;` would be clearer - _maybe_ not as fast.

Comment: abs(u) means u will ALWAYS be positive; it's the absolute value. The if statement is therefore always true. Because u is always greater than 0 (always positive) it will always be 1 as a result. However this is not the case with u < 0, therefore that part of the statement is 0. 1 - 0 = 1; therefore u = Vdc * 1, and is therefore the entire code is equivalent to u = Vdc. Whether the integer is signed or not is irrelevant; it's always positive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `u > 0` the statement will become `1 - 0` (true - false) = `1`. If `u < 0` it will become `-1`. If it is zero, it will become `0` as well. So basically it is returning the "sign" of `u` (or more precisely `1` with corresponding sign). The overall code snippet is for clamping `u` between `+Vdc` and `-Vdc`. (As suggested, it will work only for positive `Vdc`).

Comment: The caveat worth noting is that `Vdc` would have to be positive for this to be true. If `Vdc` were negative, `u` would fall in the set of all real numbers.

Comment: Note that clamping may not occur if `u == INT_MIN` due to `abs(u)` may return a negative value.

Comment: and actually I would like to amend my comment. If `Vdc` were negative, then `u` could only equal +/-`Vdc` after this snippet

Comment: @mstbaum It is still valid comment, since the code is obviously not designed for such a scenario

Comment: @chux: That's UB, not a negative value. GCC optimizes `if(abs(x) < 0)` to `if(0)`, for example.

Comment: @mafso True that `int(INT_MIN)` could be undefined behavior C11 7.22.6.1 2.  A common undefined behavior result is that `int(INT_MIN)` returns `INT_MIN` : a negative value.  IAC, `abs(INT_MIN)` is a problem.

Comment: @chux: As illustrated with `if(abs(x) < 0)`, Gcc makes use of that UB and assumes `INT_MIN` is never passed to `abs` (tested with 4.7.2 and 4.9.2). Though I'm not sure if I got what you're saying; what is "IAC"?

Answer (score 5):

The expression in parentheses is the sign function.
If `u > 0` holds, the expression becomes

```
(u > 0) - (u < 0) -> 1 - 0 -> 1
```

because the first condition is true and the second is false.
Same for the `u < 0` case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technique to model the function

```
    |0,  if u = 0
 f= |1,  if u > 0
    |-1, if u < 0
```

It avoids using an if clause to do this comparison, and evaluates like so

```
//For positive values of u 
(u>0) - (u<0) = 1 - 0 = 1
//For negative values of u
(u>0) - (u<0) = 0 - 1 = -1
//For u = 0
(u>0) - (u<0) = 0 - 0 = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mathematical function [Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)
it's value is

1. 1 if u > 0
2. 0 if u = 0
3. -1 if u < 0

this is how it works:

as per C standard section 6.5.8 relational operators

> shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int.

now if u is greater than 0 then `u > 0` returns 1 and `u < 0` returns 0. `1-0` is 1, e.g. any `u` greater than 0 converted to 1. Similarly, any `u` less than 0 is converted into -1.